# Problemas con calcular distancia entre varios puntos

Tags: javascript, mysql, html5, google-geocoding-api, geolocation-api

Tengo este codigo

> Calcula la distancia entre 2 puntos

```
async  function CalcularAuto(restaurantes){

            await geocode();
            //await geodestination();
                    latB.push(restaurantes.Latitud);
                    lonB.push(restaurantes.Longitud);
                    var latLocation = latP; 
                    var lngLocation = longP; 
                    
                    var latDestination =  latB; 
                    var lngDestination =  lonB; 
                        
                
                    
                        var getDistance =  function(latLocation,lngLocation,latDestination,lngDestination) {
                            const deg2rad = deg => (deg * Math.PI) / 180.0;
                            var R = 6371;
                            var dLat = deg2rad(latDestination-latLocation);
                            var dLon = deg2rad(lngDestination-lngLocation);
                            var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(deg2rad(latLocation)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(latDestination)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) 
                            * Math.sin(dLon/2);


                    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
                    var d = R * c;
                    return d; 
                        }
   
    
                    function de2rad(n){return n * (Math.PI/180)}
                    var d = getDistance(latLocation,lngLocation , latDestination,lngDestination );
                    latB = [];
                    lonB = [];
                    var distanciaTemp = 0;
                    console.log((d).toFixed(2)+ "km");
                    distanciaTemp = ((d).toFixed(2));
                    if(menor == 0){
                        menor = distanciaTemp;
                        latt = latDestination;
                        longg = lngDestination;
                    }
                    if(menor >= distanciaTemp){
                        menor = distanciaTemp;
                        latt = latDestination;
                        longg = lngDestination;

                        
                        return restaurantes;
                    }
                    return null;
}
```

> Toma el valor que tiene el input y lo transforma a coordenadas

```
async  function geocode(){
              
            
             
            var location = document.getElementById('direccion').value;
            //location = latP +","+ longP;
            if (location == "") {
                
            }else{
                await  axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',{
                params:{
                    address:location,
                    key:'[YOUR_API_KEY]'
                    
                }
            })
            .then(function(response){
                // Log full response
               // console.log(response);

                // Formatted Address
                var formattedAddress = response.data.results[0].formatted_address;
                var formattedAddressOutput =
                 `
                    <ul class = "list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">${formattedAddress}</li>
                    </ul>
                `;

                // Address componets
                    var addressComponents = response.data.results[0].address_components;
                        var addressComponentOutput = 
                        `
                        <ul class = "list-group">
                        `;
                        for (var i = 0; i < addressComponents.length; i++) {
                            addressComponentOutput += 
                            `
                                <li class="list-group-item"><strong>${addressComponents[i].types[0]}
                                </strong>: ${addressComponents[i].long_name}</li>
                            `;                            
                        }
                    addressComponentOutput += '</ul>';
                    

         // Geometry
         var latLocation = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
         var lngLocation = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        
         latP = latLocation;
         longP = lngLocation;
         
                   /*      var geometryOutput = 
                        `
                        <ul class = "list-group">
                            <li id="latLocation" class="list-group-item"><strong>Latitude</strong>:
                            ${latLocation}
                                
                            </li>

                            <li id = "lngLocation" class="list-group-item"><strong>Longitude</strong>:
                            ${lngLocation}
                                
                            </li>
                        </ul>`;
                                  */                       
                        
                           



                    

                })
            .catch(function(error){
               // console.log(error);
            })
            }
           
}
```

toma los datos desde un input y los envia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado desde consola, efectivamente me esta tomando el menor valor osea la menor distancia y la muestra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero hay momentos en lo que esto falla dependiendo de la direccion, esto es lo que muestra en la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que pregunta si el menor es mayor a la distancia tomada en distanciaTemp, si lo es entonces a menor le asigna lo que contenga distanciaTemp

```
if(menor == 0){
                        menor = distanciaTemp;
                        latt = latDestination;
                        longg = lngDestination;
                    }
                    if(menor >= distanciaTemp){
                        menor = distanciaTemp;
                        latt = latDestination;
                        longg = lngDestination;

                        
                        return restaurantes;
                    }
                    return null;
```

por alguna extraña razon, al momento de pregunta si 6.81 es mayor a 10.23, este dice que si lo es y no deberia ser asi.

otro ejemplo:

si en el input escribo como direccion "Soledad, Atlántico" pasa esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las direcciones que tengo asignada en la base de datos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Este es el codigo de consulta a la base de datos y toma las direcciones

```
async   function consultarRestaurantes() {
    fetch('http://localhost/ecommerce/ecommerce/ecommerce/api/consultar.php', {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
            .then(restaurantes => {
                agregarRestaurantesTabla(restaurantes);
                
            })
}
```

> Consultar.php

```
  <?php

// http://localhost/sistema_php/api/consultar.php
  $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "appecomerce") or die("not connected".mysqli_connect_error());

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_restaurantes`;";

  $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
  
  $restaurantes = array();
  while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($restaurantes, $fila);
  }
  
  echo json_encode($restaurantes);

  mysqli_free_result($result);
  mysqli_close($conexion);
  

?>
```

> Formato en Texto de la imagen de la tabla de datos

```
    1   McDonals Calle 93   Cra. 46 #No. 93-10, Barranquilla, Atlántico Si  11.004814286810749  -74.82763763213357
2   McDonals    Cl. 80 #No. 51B-10, Barranquilla, Atlántico 24 Horas    11.004039581617151  -74.81271143213358
3   Drogueria la rebaja plus    Cra. 41 ##58-103, Barranquilla, Atlántico   24Horas 10.984260699978947  -74.79738559396759
4   FarmaTodo   Carrera 65 # 86 - 125, Barranquilla Si  11.017597181486195  -74.81342602037543
5   Centro Comercial Nuestro Atlantico  Av. Murillo #131 a 13-167, Soledad, Barranquilla, Atlántico     10.905670926327327  -74.80212241485586
6   Centro Comercial Portal De Soledad  Av. Murillo #14, Barranquilla, Soledad, Atlántico       10.909393484447167  -74.79884602833592
```

Comment: Intenta parserar los valores a float, puede que esta tomandolo como algun valor distinto, eso es lo que te recomendaria yo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segun tus ejemplos siempre te esta trayendo el menor... 0, 1... o lo que sea menor...

Pero si hacemos un analisis, fijate:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el menor, es 1 seguido de un 0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es 0..

Lo que me da la impresión, de que estas tomando los números como texto.

Entonces mirando tu código, se ve que antes de comparar con el menor, haces esto:

```
distanciaTemp = ((d).toFixed(2));
```

Y si vamos a la [definición](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) de lo que hace, dice:

> El método toFixed() formatea un número usando notación de punto fijo.

> Valor Devuelto
> Una cadena que representa el número dado, usando notación de punto fijo.

Por lo tanto, como no hay una definición estática del tipo de variables en js, y la función la transformo a cadena, entonces esta comparando como cadena...

Recomendación, hace primero todas las comparaciones necesarios en todos lados, y por ultimo, hace la transformación para mostrarlo...